# Can I load 8bit bitmaps with Blender?

Tags: scripting, texturing, file-format

After looking at the [documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Formats) about supported file formats on wiki, I tried to use 8 bit BMP files as texture. (I know, old school, but I wanted to avoid conversions)

However, the image appears blank in blender.

**Is there anything I need to set** (like a property, or parameter while importing) **to be able to use an 8bit BMP image as texture?**
When I convert these to PNG or 24b BMP there is no problem.
Also when I save something with [mspaint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint_%28software%29) as 8b BMP the same problem happens.

Note I used a python script to import these, `image.load()`.

Comment: just as a heads up .BMP is a bad format for blender and several other 3d apps. Use .tga or .png or .exr. Those three will have you covered for most of your needs. Also .HDR exist for environment maps. Do not be too lazy to convert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not supported, the *Import Image as Plane* addon prints (console)

```
IMB_ibImageFromMemory: unknown fileformat
```

Trying to open a 8 bit BMP manually also prints "Unknown fileformat" on the console window.

The difference to 16, 24 and 32 bit BMPs is that 256-Colors are adressed from a [palette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palette_(computing)) this makes the file format different to the other formats.

If you have many images to convert you could consider batch-converting them with [ImageMagic, Gimp or Irfanview](https://superuser.com/questions/77429/using-gimp-to-batch-convert-images-to-another-format-in-windows)

Comment: Actually a fix for this was committed yesterday. Try an svn build of r59103 or higher. This fix will be part of 2.69

Comment: @sambler as long as the feature is available in some form. It is fine to answer.

Answer (score 5):

Support for loading 8bit bitmaps was just committed to trunk recently. Grab any build of [r59103](https://projects.blender.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=bf-blender&revision=59103) or greater and it should work and it will also be available by default in 2.69.

Comment: I downloaded 2.69 and tried this. The bitmaps now load, but incorrectly. After I use same texture in 24 bits, it will be allright.

Comment: @Zéiksz You could report this as a bug then, it was working at the time I tried it and wrote this answer.